# Sass Placeholders from Mixins

Tags: css, sass

I want to create Sass placeholders on the fly using arbitrary values passed from a style block:

```
@mixin example-mixin($arg) {
    %placeholder-#{$arg} {
        property: $arg;
    }
    @extend %placeholder-#{$arg};
}
```

Calling the mixin:

```
.classname {
    @include example-mixin('value');
}
```

This almost works, but for some reason in the CSS output the `.classname` is given twice as though it's a descendant selector:

```
.classname .classname {
    property: value;
}
```

I'm not seeing the logic behind the duplicate class names - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and/or suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what happens if you use real classes instead of extend classes

```
.a {
    .b {
        color: blue;
    }

    @extend .b;
}
```

Output:

```
.a .b, .a .a {
  color: blue;
}
```

The only reason I could imagine you wanting to do this is so you can use the extend class for purposes of extending instead of `.classname` like so:

```
.c {
    @extend .b;
}
```

You'll see that the output probably isn't what you want at all:

```
.a .b, .a .a, .a .c {
  color: blue;
}
```

The `.a .a` doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me either, but it's harmless.  What you're actually wanting to do is something like this:

```
%placeholder-name, .classname {
    property: name;
}

.foo {
    @extend %placeholder-name;
}
```

And the output will be like this:

```
.foo, .classname {
  property: name;
}
```